# Is having the name of web server software in HTTP response header a serious problem?

Tags: server, header, information-gathering

How serious a security problem is it to have the name of the web server in the HTTP header (Apache, Nginx etc.)?

I am discussing this with a system administrator and he told me that deleting version is easy, but deleting the name of the server (in our case nginx) is not so simple and it takes more time.

So, he thinks that it is useless, because, there are a lot of tools that are able to detect the type of server based on HTTP header.

On the other side, I have always read that information like this should be removed.

My question is - Is information like this a serious problem and should be removed, or not? (I assume fully patched server)

Comment: If you visit https://www.netflix.com/404 then it will reveal `server: nq_website_nonmember-prod-release b521e844-f2f6-4b97-8c9f-0e0d05283f97`. Netflix decided it was more important to reveal details about a problematic web request than it was to obscure this information from script kiddies. https://www.microsoft.com/404 reveals `x-azure-ref`. As long as you're not using something defunct like [AOL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOLserver) then hiding the version number would suffice in my opinion. You need to specify your threat model.

Comment: Please specify HTTP **Response** header. I came to look at this question because I was thinking the name of the server was absolutely **required** in the Request header. :)

Comment: Not only is it not a serious problem: it is not a problem at all. Letting attackers know the type of web-server, the version of it, what OS it's running on, the name of the machine it's on, and how it's configured, does not affect the *security* of the system. It only affects the *obscurity* of the system. And obscurity is **not** security.

Comment: @IanBoyd I would agree if it weren't for the utterly reprehensible state of software security that exists today.  Consider this scenario: a critical vulnerability for your webserver is published while you are sleeping.  Guess what happens next?  A bunch of nefarious actors looking for any vulnerable servers.  Do you really want to make their job easy?  Now weigh that against the benefit of telling your clients what webserver you use.

Comment: @JimmyJames Do you really think it would make their job any harder? Do you really believe widespread attacks happen because a vulnerability gets "published" while ever-vigilant admins are sleeping and can't patch it? If your organization is so big you do have a team constantly monitoring vulnerabilities, and I mean *constantly*, everyone who cares pretty much knows what you're running anyway. Sorry, this threat model sounds like pure fantasy to me.

Comment: @Lodinn If you run any non-serverless webservers in AWS, I suggest you look at your access logs.  I find it incredible how many dumb attempts are made.  Just pure spray.  It's kind of like the old parable of the two people running from the bear: you don't need to outrun the bear, just the other person.  As always, it depends on your threat model.  But the fact of the matter is that basically everyone is exposed to the threat model of script kiddies looking for vulnerable servers.

Comment: @Lodinn Also, I should add that as a prolific consumer of services, I have never (not once) needed to know or cared what webserver the host is using.  If you need your clients need to know what webserver you are running, you are "doing it wrong™"

Comment: @JimmyJames No, I do not happen to run servers in AWS, but I've seen a lot of dumb spray attempts. The bear parable was what sprung to my mind as I was writing the earlier comment indeed but it still mostly depends on how fast you run, not whether you throw something at the bear while doing so. I did get one of my VMs breached a while ago but it took it sitting unattended for basically half an year. With big vulnerabilities, they do not even try to check if it even could be applicable to your server, they just fire it and see what hit the ground as Guntram has pointed out.

Comment: And regular consumers surely do not care, but I've also seen enough (bad) parsing code reliant on the specific header structure and whatnot. More importantly, adjusting it is an overhead that needs some maintenance: maybe not a lot of effort, after all, but the gains are also marginal.

Comment: @JimmyJames Whats to stop the attacker just trying the vulnerability anyway? How many of the attacks you see are wordpress vulnerability attacks against server that aren't running anything to do with wordpress because its cheaper to run the attack than it is to check if the server is running wordpress. If you can't patch it in time you are going to get broken into.

Comment: @user1937198 Kind of depends on how much effort the attack takes, doesn't it?  At the end of the day, no one should really need to know what you are running.  AFAICT, this feature has benefits only for attackers.  Any decent server or proxy should have a way to disable it.  The security consultants I've worked with say to remove this header and there's basically no cost to doing it.  If your platform doesn't have a simple configuration option to remove it, maybe consider a better platform.

Comment: @Lodinn "Do you really believe widespread attacks happen because a vulnerability gets "published" while ever-vigilant admins are sleeping and can't patch it?"  Consider (https://assets.sophos.com/X24WTUEQ/at/rgbjvgnx6qwwj7wvx764rmbn/sophos-exposed-cyberattacks-on-cloud-honeypots-wp.pdf)[this study] where vulnerable servers were set up on AWS to see how long it would take for them to be accessed: the TL;DR is as fast as a minute and best-case: 2 hours.  Now consider that a potential attacker would already know what your server is running at the moment vulnerability is known.

Comment: @JimmyJames Was not my point, user1937198 gets it. A potential attacker does not really care as much whether your server actually runs vulnerable software these days. Notably, the article you linked was not about zero-day vulnerabilities in ssh itself or how long did it take between a vulnerability appearing on the CVE list and widespread attacks exploiting it, big difference here. The lowest hanging fruit always will be misconfigured software, from the attacker's perspective you update the password list once in blue moon and it just brings you money. Low effort, big gains.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Assuming that the server is fully patched and you're just talking about product name and not version, I wouldn't generally regard this as a serious problem.

Essentially all security hardening is a trade-off between effort and risk reduction. Here you would potentially be reducing the risk marginally of a successful attack, but at the cost of effort to implement. In reality there's likely other places the same effort could be spent, to better effect.

In an *ideal* world you don't give possible attackers any information you don't have to as it makes their lives harder and forces them to spend more effort on each attack, but with things like product name (especially for common products like nginx) that's a pretty marginal benefit.

Comment: It's fully patched until it isn't.  That's the problem.

Answer (score 41):

Any competent vulnerability scanner won't check for headers or similar information; instead, it'll just try dozens or hundreds of known attacks and checks if one if them works.

Why that? Because there's so many reasons why the header info might be wrong.

You might, for example, be using a long term release of Ubuntu, Debian, or RedHat. In long term releases, they typically fix the version number when the release comes out; during the lifetime of the OS release, they'll backport fixes but won't upgrade the version. So your "SuperServer 1.2.3" will, after a while, still announce itself as "Superserver 1.2.3" but include all the fixes (but not features) up to version 1.2.17.

For all but the smallest web sites, you'll connect to some kind of load balancer or reverse proxy which distributes your request to one of several  backend servers. But there's only one `server` header. So even if it says `Server: nginx` you may be successful trying some apache exploit - attack the backend apache even with an nginx-based load balancer. Or vice versa.

So, any automated scanner will just try out as much as it can in order to not miss out on anything.

20-25 years ago, this kind of automated vulnerability scanning didn't exist, or at least wasn't as widespread/easy to as today. In those days, some people would actually try to find out stuff about server software, look up vulnerability lists, and try exploit those manually, themselves. But today? Not a chance.

Comment: With easy access to high bandwidth connections and zombie bot-nets, there's just no point performing precision attacks when carpet bombing is easier and more reliable. The internet is literally a giant threat actor and you should protect your server as such anyways.

Answer (score 10):

On the long list of things you can do to protect a server on the internet, not exposing the name of the web server barely rates.

The version number may be of more concern, since it may in theory help attackers target older or known vulnerable servers.  But even this may not be particularly useful, since older servers may still be patched or may not have the vulnerable part enabled/configured.

By the time an attacker has put in the effort to query your server to try and determine what software it's running, it may as well just have probed for the actual vulnerability anyway which in most cases would be more efficient.

Comment: I think you are getting the process backwards.  The attacker could already know what it's running, because you told them before the vulnerability was found.  It's trivial to maintain a list of servers and what platform they report they are running.  In other words, they don't need to query your server.  They just go attack it because they know it's a potential target.

Comment: Jimmy I am having trouble understanding what you mean.  You say it's trivial to maintain a list of servers and their platforms, but it isn't really, that indicates you've already done the work to query a lot of servers to try and fingerprint them, and stored the results.  If you took the same starting list of IP addresses and just tried to run exploits on them one by one, you are doing both in one pass and you don't need to store any results in the meantime.  Program the exploit so it fails fast if it's not going to work and it shouldn't take significantly longer either.

Answer (score 0):

It is a security concern to include the web server name and version in the HTTP response header. While not a vulnerability, your team and you should have a benefits-risk balance.

When an attacker looks for a vulnerability, their first step is information gathering. Here a common scenario would be web server fingerprinting. This to be sure with what type of file structure the attacker has to expect from the web server.

We suppose the latest patches for your webserver. It does not stop the attacker from making oriented guesses about web server languages. This can also assist attackers in exploiting other vulnerabilities that may exist.

When this kind of data is absent or obfuscated, the attacker has to change strategies. He has to rely on other means to identify web server technologies. They use [automated, dedicated tools to compare the webserver behavior](https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/latest/4-Web_Application_Security_Testing/01-Information_Gathering/02-Fingerprint_Web_Server) to certain requests. Also, the tools analyse server response time to certain requests across the network.

1. Let's suppose you hide the headers. You can provide fewer clues to inexperienced hackers. Also, waste a little bit more time to more experienced attackers.
2. But some companies prefer to include them. This is because they want better monitoring of their own infrastructure.  Can your production team have another safer way of checking the server version?

A group like OWASP believe that the first is the correct way to go.

Answer (score -1):

"I am discussing this with a system administrator and he told me that deleting version is easy, but deleting the name of the server (in our case nginx) is not so simple and it takes more time."

[How much time does it really take?](https://kodemonk.dev/blog/setting-custom-sever-header-in-nginx)

- Go to nginx config folder (cd /etc/nginx/) and open the configuration file (nginx.conf)
- Add server_tokens off; under http section.
- Restart Nginx webserver (sudo systemctl restart nginx)

You've spent more time asking this question, I imagine.

Comment: That only hides version information, NOT the name `nginx`. To remove the header, you have to use an empty string, which in turn is only available when you have a commercial subscription.